# How to pass object over a URL in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have an object which I get in the jsp file from the servlet.
I want to pass this object over to another jsp file and display the contents in the other jsp file.

**1st Jsp file:**

```
ChangeRoomVO vo=(ChangeRoomVO)request.getAttribute("booking");
<a href="ChangeValidate.jsp?booking=<%=vo%>"><input type="button" value="Change"></a>
```

**2nd jsp file:**

```
ChangeRoomVO vo=(ChangeRoomVO)request.getAttribute("booking");
out.print(vo.getBookingId());
```

The **error** says:

```
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
> JSP page /ChangeValidate.jsp at line 14
> 
> 11: <body>
  12: <% 
  13: ChangeRoomVO vo=(ChangeRoomVO)request.getAttribute("booking"); 
  14: out.print(vo.getBookingId());
  root cause
  java.lang.NullPointerException
```

the URL is able to pass the object but is not able to retrieve the data stored in it.
Is there a work around which allows passing objects over URL?

Comment: This will help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065184/passing-server-side-objects-from-one-jsp-page-to-another

Comment: You can only pass strings via the URL, not objects. And even for strings you must carefully escape special characters.

Comment: In line 14, clearly the "booking" object is not being passed to 2nd JSP. Are these to JSPs being called in the same HTTP request, or are you forwarding b/w urls?

Comment: I think you're going to need to store your "ChangeRoomVO" in the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is little odd to me. You cannot pass Objects over in the query.

But you have options.

- Implement `toString()` method with some separator and set as a String and retrieve in
  another jsp.**(not recommended)**
- And if the jsp's processing on same request, set the Object to
  request with `req.serAttribute("obj", Obj)`
- If both jsps are differes in request set the Object to session like
  `session.setAttribute("obj", Obj)`

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use Session.What you are trying with request won't work.Because All the JSPs will become servelt then as Text/html.So in Text/html file there are no attributes.